# Control Visual Studio 2017 from command line/package manager/powershell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2017

I am aware of the PowerShell object `$dte`, but I am wondering if their are other possibilities to control actions like `Rebuild Solution`, `Clean Solution` etc?

As my PowerShell prompt ist opened anyway all the time (using Posh-Git, .etc) it would be handy to control other Visual Studio Tasks straight from the PS console.

Answer (score 0):

The [DTE documentation for SolutionBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionbuild?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) has some VB code that was pretty easy to translate to Powershell:

```
$dte = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('VisualStudio.DTE')
$sb = $dte.Solution.SolutionBuild
$sb.SolutionConfigurations['Debug'].Activate  #Or maybe you want 'Release'
$sb.Build()
```

The SolutionBuild interface has other interesting methods: `Clean()`, `Debug()` and `Run()`. 
You were probably already aware, but the console needs to be running as Administrator to get the DTE handle.